# Convert avro serialized messages into json using python consumer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, kafka-python

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json
import io

if __name__ == '__main__':

  # consumer = KafkaConsumer(
  #     'ldt_lm_mytable',
  #     bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:9092',
  #     auto_offset_reset = 'earliest',
  #     group_id = 'consumer_group_a')

  KAFKA_HOSTS = ['kafka:9092']
  KAFKA_VERSION = (0, 10)
  topic = "ldt_lm_mytable"

  consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_HOSTS, api_version=KAFKA_VERSION)

  for msg in consumer:
    print('Lead = {}'.format(json.loads(msg.value)))
```

There is nothing printing. I am using avro converter when producing data into topic (Debezium). I've tried some converters from internet. But those are not working. One of those is like this

```
bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(consumer)
decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
reader = avro.io.DatumReader(schema)
decoded_data = reader.read(decoder)
```

In this converter from where I will get that 'schema' variable's value? How do I load that 'avro' package? And that 'io.BytesIO' giving me an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "consumer.py", line 19, in <module>
bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(consumer)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'KafkaConsumer'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use the json converter if that's the format you want to consume? And you're looking for `io.BytesIO(msg.value)` if the data were not serialized using the Confluent Avro format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Debezium connector is using the standard `io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter` in Kafka Connect then you need to use the Avro deserialiser that goes with the Confluent Schema Registry.

Here's an example consumer [from here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python):

```py
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroConsumer
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import SerializerError


c = AvroConsumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'mybroker,mybroker2',
    'group.id': 'groupid',
    'schema.registry.url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8081'})

c.subscribe(['my_topic'])

while True:
    try:
        msg = c.poll(10)

    except SerializerError as e:
        print("Message deserialization failed for {}: {}".format(msg, e))
        break

    if msg is None:
        continue

    if msg.error():
        print("AvroConsumer error: {}".format(msg.error()))
        continue

    print(msg.value())

c.close()
```